# ExtJS 4.1 How to create a window with grid dynamically

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, window

I'm a new ExtJS user and I've a question.

I have a store with cars and I create a menu with buttons to see all cars by brand or model.
Now I want to display a window with a grid panel containing all my cars for a particular brand/model.
Actually when I create my buttons i do that :

```
var aCarButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: aTextButton,
    handler: function() {
        var aResultWindow = new ResultWindow(aTextButton, myCarStore, 'Brand', aBrandValue);
        aResultWindow.create();
    }
});
aMenuPanel.add(aCarButton);
```

For my functions I do that :

```
function ResultWindow(aTitle, aStore, aFilter, aFilterValue) {
    this.myTitle = aTitle;
    this.myStore = aStore;
    this.myFilter = aFilter;
    this.myFilterValue = aFilterValue;
    this.myStore.filter(aFilter, aFilterValue); 
}

ResultWindow.prototype.create = function() {
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: this.myStore,
        columns: [
            ...
        ]
    });
    var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        layout: 'fit',
        maximizable: true,
        title: this.myTitle,
        items: [ grid ],
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    });
    window.show();
}
```

Firstly I'm not sure that is the best way to display what I want.
And Secondly I have a button that display all cars (no filters) but that take about 2 min to display all my 12000 record.

So my first question is to know if my solution to display what I want is correct ?
And my second question if is it possible to display all cars faster ?

PS : Sorry for my English if I did some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is certainly a way to do it but i don't think it is the best way to do it in Ext, i'll do something among these lines:

```
var aCarButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
text: aTextButton,
handler: function() {
        myCarStore.filter('Brand', aBrandvalue);
        var win = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
            title: aTextButton,
            layout: 'fit',
            maximizable: true,
            width: 1024,
            height: 768,
            items:[{
                xtype: 'grid',
                store: myCarStore,
                columns: [
                    ...
                ]
            }]
        });
        win.show();
});
aMenuPanel.add(aCarButton);
```

I'm declaring the Window inline just for the sake of the example, i would probably go for a custom Window with the grid included and some custom functions to filter on the grid but, the main point: you don't need to mess with prototype here, there is no need really, if all you want is control how your Window is created, then `define` one like this:

```
Ext.define("CarsWindow", {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    items:[
        ...
    ],
    filterByBrand: function(brandValue){
        this.down('grid').getStore().filter('Brand', brandValue);
    },
    ...
});
```

And then you can instantiate it via:

```
Ext.create("CarsWindow", { title: 'YourTitle', ...}).show();
```

For your second question, there is a way to show large datasets in Ext without losing too much performance, you can set `buffered: true` on your store definition and, then, call ´store.loadPage(1)´ more on this: [store.buffered](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-buffered)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that going really help me. Now I'm going to try this and I will send you a feedback

Comment: So I defined my CarsWindow and put set items like this items: [{ xtype:'grid', store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myCarStore'), columns: [ ... ] }]. But now when I instantiate it my grid displays no data. Of course my store have a storeId: 'myCarStore'.

Comment: Ok, don't consider my 2nd comment. I refactored my code and it's better now.